# How to access texts from language files from the code section?

Tags: inno-setup

In Inno Setup one can access texts from the language files e.g. the following way (where CreateDesktopIcon is the text entry to look for):

```
[Tasks]
Name: "TaskDesktopIcon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; Flags:
```

My question is how to access texts from the language files from the code section of the Inno Setup script?

I have tried the following, but the compiler will not accept the syntax:

```
[code]
var
  pageAutoLogon: TWizardPage;

procedure CreateAutoLogonPage;
begin 
   pageAutoLogon := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectTasks, "{cm:AutoLogonCredentialsTitle}", "{cm:AutoLogonCredentialsDescription}");
...
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`ExpandConstant`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) (or [`ExpandConstantEx`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstantex)) function to evaluate a constant in script code. Like this way for instance:

```
procedure CreateAutoLogonPage;
begin 
  pageAutoLogon := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectTasks, ExpandConstant('{cm:AutoLogonCredentialsTitle}'), ExpandConstant('{cm:AutoLogonCredentialsDescription}'));
  ...
end;
```

Comment: It's normally best to use the native functions rather than passing through `ExpandConstant` where there is no actual dynamic content.

Comment: @Deanna, yup. I've suggested this as an immediate answer to the code in the question. I'm free for reaccept to your answer and deleting mine, since I don't see any reason having two posts speaking about two different ways to do what is asked. It's better to make just one including all the ways suggesting the best.

Comment: Well, SO is designed for multiple answers and the "best" gets listed first/most rep :)

Comment: @Deanna, well, SO is designed so, but I'm thinking of future readers. I don't personally like reading many posts to see all the options I have to the same problem when searching for something. It saves the time and mouse wheel :) John, prefer the other way posted here (`SetupMessage`). Could you re-accept the other answer, please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`CustomMessage()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_custommessage.htm) function to retrieve the values from the `[CustomMessages]` section.

```
pageAutoLogon := CreateCustomPage(wpSelectTasks, CustomMessage('AutoLogonCredentialsTitle'), CustomMessage('AutoLogonCredentialsDescription'));
```

For normal `[Messages]`, you can use the [`SetupMessage()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_setupmessage.htm) with one of the enum values.